# lista para guardar objetos

Tags: java

bom, estou criando uma lista de fabricante e tenho uma duvida referente qual coleção usar.

Quero adicionar vários fabricantes na minha lista, no caso uso o ArrayList da interface LIST? ou algum na interface SET que não permite duplicação?

Comment: List é somente interface, não há implementação alguma, arraylist que é a implementação de List. Sua pergunta é baseado em opinião, quem pode decidir o que é melhor para sua aplicação é somente você mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende de quais funcionalidades você quer na sua coleção. Basicamente as diferenças entre um `Set<T>` e um `List<T>` são:

- Um `List<T>` aceita elementos duplicados, já um `Set<T>` não;
- Um `List<T>` é, obrigatoriamente, ordenado enquanto em um `Set<T>` isso é opcional e depende da implementação. Exemplo: os elementos de um `HashSet<T>` não são ordenados, já os elementos de um `TreeSet<T>` são ordenados de acordo com o `Comparator<T>` definido.
- Um `List<T>` permite que você acesse elementos através de sua posição, um `Set<T>` não permite isso.

Sendo assim, basta ver quais funcionalidades você necessita e escolher a coleção mais adequada. No seu caso, provavelmente não faça sentido ter fabricantes duplicados na sua coleção, assim um `Set<T>` seria a melhor opção.

É importante também ressaltar que um `Set<T>` verifica se existem elementos duplicados na coleção através dos métodos `hashCode` e `equals`. Então, dependendo do que você considera como objetos iguais no seu domínio, seria necessário sobrescrever esses métodos para que o `Set<T>` identifique duplicatas de uma forma correta.

Além disso, pela forma que um `Set<T>` funciona, o uso de elementos mutáveis é desencorajado, já que, a partir do momento em que um objeto é alterado, o resultado dos métodos `hashCode` e `equals` também podem ser alterados. E nesse cenário, o comportamento de um `Set<T>` não é especificado.